# MediaPlayer stops playing after a while

Tags: java, android

My android app needs to play a warning tone to the user every 5 seconds or so if its connection to the server is broken.

So every 5 seconds it executes this code

```
MediaPlayer np = MediaPlayer.create(globals.MainContext, R.raw.warn);
np.start();
```

Its a short mp3 sound clip that lasts maybe 2 seconds. It plays a few times then doesnt play anymore. I looked at the log and "AudioFlinger: it says not enough memory for audio track", then a bunch of related audio complaints after that.

Is it because i keep creating a new MediaPlayer again and again? I thought it would get garbage collected and removed when the sound stops automaically?, should i just create it once and keep the object around?

Anybody knows?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes as you suggested, don't create a new MediaPlayer every time. So create the MediaPlayer object then every 5 seconds execute only `np.start();`

Comment: Awesome! Just learned about it the other day while doing the Udacity Android Basics Nanodegree. Anyway don't forget to mark my answer as accepted :) Cheers.